# Why does viewing PGP encrypted PDF fail?

Tags: microsoft-windows, pdf, docview, gpg, epa

When I try to open a PGP encrypted PDF `file.pdf.gpg`, then – after entering the PIN in my smartcard reader – a window pops up with an error message:

```
Error: /syntaxerror in (binary token, type=150)
Operand stack:
   -117240830   -2063108939
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
lse   1   %stopped_push   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_
pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   1836   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval-
-   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringv
al--   2   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1200/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Close this window with the close button on the title bar or the system menu.
```

I would expect the PDF to be shown in DocView mode.

About my system:

- Windows 7 x64
- GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570
- Viewing PDFs in DocView mode works fine.
- Viewing PGP encrypted text files with EasyPG Assistant (epa) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a encrypted file, Emacs automatically replaces the contents of it's buffer with a decrypted version of it.  Though `doc-view`, and for that matter `pdf-view` as well, does not care for the actual buffer content, but rather uses the buffer's file-name with various programs, in your case ghostscript, in order to produce images of the PDF pages.  Since the actual file stays encrypted, these programs fail to do their job.

`doc-view` already handles files in archives and remote files, by copying them to a temporary file and using this file with said programs.  It would be relatively easy to extend this behavior to encrypted files, but maybe this is considered a security risk. Or no one has thought of it yet.

Comment: *Can support for decryption be added to `doc-view` simply by customizing options, or would the `doc-view` code need to be changed?* If the temporary location where `doc-view` places a temporary file is on a RAM disk, then this should be safe.

Comment: You definitely would have to add some code somewhere.